# Performance tuning on pattern matching query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I have two tables:

Table 1: 100 rows

Table 2: 10 Millions rows

Example:

Table 1: `tb100`

```
create table tb100
(
    name varchar(50)
);

insert into tb100 values('Mak John'),('Will Smith'),('Luke W')......100 rows.
```

Table 2: `tb10mil`

```
create table tb10mil
(
    name varchar(50)
);

insert into tb10mil values('John A Mak'),('K Smith Will'),('James Henry')......10 millions rows.    

create nonclustered index nci_tb10mil_name  on tb10mil(name);
```

Note: I want to match the name between two tables, if any **WORD**(John,Smith,Will) present in another table. For example `John` present in `John A Mark`.

My try:

Firstly I have created User Defined Function for splitting the `name` of `tb100` into rows.

Function: `udf_Split`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Split]
(
@InputString VARCHAR(8000), 
@Delimiter VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS @Items TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1), Item VARCHAR(8000))

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END
      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

      DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END 

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END
```

And then I wrote following query:

```
;with splitdata as
(
    select f.item as data
    from tb100 t
    cross apply dbo.udf_split(t.name,' ') f
)
select t2.name 
from tb10mil t2
inner join splitdata c on charindex(c.data,t2.name)>0
group by t2.name
```

Above query is taking more than 20 minutes time to execute.

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE` loop for your splitter? There are plenty of dataset solutions out there that will be far faster. I would suggest using an XML splitter or delimitedsplit8k (if it's not an `nvarchar(MAX)`). That splitter is very likely your (first) problem..

Comment: First of all SQL isn't a text processing language so you can't expect good text splitting performance. Second, without indexes you can't improve performance, and that function can't use indexes. Finally, SQL Server already has full text search capabilities and fuzzy matching and lookups in SSIS. If you want to fuzzily match names while loading 10M rows, use a Fuzzy lookup operator in SSIS

Comment: If you want to match eg a sales table with a set of customer records by name, do so while loading the data and only store actual IDs in the target table. Don't try to repeat the fuzzy lookup every time you want to join the tables. No matter which technique you use, a fuzzy match will always be slower than a join over two indexed columns

Comment: If this query will be used frequently, then it is better to maintain a mapping table from an AFTER trigger on the main tables and keep splitted data in as table column values. Then joins can be built upon this new mapping table

Comment: To split string using SQL FOR XML PATH method, following UDF function can be an alternative http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like following.

```
  ;WITH splitdata 
     AS (SELECT splitname 
         FROM   (SELECT *, 
                        Cast('<X>' + Replace(F.Name, ' ', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) 
                        AS  xmlfilter 
                 FROM   tb100 F)F1 
                CROSS apply (SELECT fdata.d.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS splitName 
                             FROM   f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(d)) O) 
SELECT DISTINCT t2.NAME 
FROM   tb10mil t2 
       INNER JOIN splitdata S 
               ON T2.NAME LIKE '%' + S.splitname + '%'
```

Comment: I really doubt, that a JOIN by LIKE on a pattern with a leading `%` will be fast with millions of rows... And just to mention this: If the names contain forbidden characters (like `<,> or &` and many more), this can break on `CAST()`. And one more hint about performance: `GROUP BY` is much faster than `DISTINCT`.

Comment: `LIKE` has nothing to do with performance in this answer. It's the *different string splitting method* that improved performance. Which will still be awful compared to using proper lookups while loading the data

Answer (score 4):

Let's speak about performance

- The first point is: Try to avoid
  scalar functions and try to avoid *multi-statement-TVFs* if ever possible. The only
  fast approach is an *inline-TVF* (a *one-line-statement*).
- The second point: Avoid loops if ever possible!
- The third point (*the very first actually*): Try to store your data in
  a format optimized for fast queries. Storing more than one value
  within one cell is violating 1NF and a huge speed killer.

You can try this:

Simulate your tables

```
CREATE TABLE #t100(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeName VARCHAR(200));
CREATE TABLE #t1M (ID INT IDENTITY,SomeName VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO #t100 VALUES('james smith'),('mak john'),('Luke W');
GO
INSERT INTO #t1M values('John A Mak'),('K Smith Will'),('James Henry'),('James John'),('Some other');
GO
```

--Create tables to store the name fragments spearately (this is the format you should use instead actually)

```
CREATE TABLE #t100Splitted(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,ID_t100 INT,Fragment NVARCHAR(200));

--Use an inline XML-splitter
INSERT INTO #t100Splitted(ID_t100,Fragment)
SELECT ID
      ,B.frg.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(200)')
FROM #t100
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT SomeName AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(CastedToXml)
CROSS APPLY A.CastedToXml.nodes('/x[text()]') B(frg);

--add indexes
CREATE INDEX IX_t100_ID_t100 ON #t100Splitted(ID_t100);
CREATE INDEX IX_t100_Fragment ON #t100Splitted(Fragment);

--The same for the second table
CREATE TABLE #t1MSplitted(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,ID_t1M INT,Fragment NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO #t1MSplitted(ID_t1M,Fragment)
SELECT ID
      ,B.frg.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(200)')
FROM #t1M
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT SomeName AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(CastedToXml)
CROSS APPLY A.CastedToXml.nodes('/x[text()]') B(frg);

CREATE INDEX IX_tM_ID_t100 ON #t1MSplitted(ID_t1M);
CREATE INDEX IX_tM_Fragment ON #t1MSplitted(Fragment);
GO

- Check the intermediate results
SELECT * FROM #t100Splitted;
SELECT * FROM #t1MSplitted;
GO
```

--This query will return all rows with common fragments
--You can re-join your source-tables to get the values back
--You can group by t2.ID_t100 in order to get the IDs of the smaller table (much faster)

```
SELECT t1.ID_t1M
FROM #t1MSplitted t1
INNER JOIN #t100Splitted t2 ON t1.Fragment=t2.Fragment
GROUP BY t1.ID_t1M
GO
```

--Clean up

```
DROP TABLE #t100;
GO
DROP TABLE #t1M;
GO
DROP TABLE #t100Splitted;
GO
DROP TABLE #t1MSplitted;
GO
```

On my system 1 Mio rows were processed in about 2 minutes.

### UPDATE  -Performance tests with 100 rows vs 10M rows

(with very many hits)

- *Just the splitting*, to transform your data into a better shape: *~17 minutes*
- The *final select* (just the look-up): *<1 minute*
- The *final select* but looking for the IDs of the small table: *some seconds*
  (once you've transformed your data, this will be *the normal speed*)
- PSK's approach (with inline-splitting): ~ 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I tried to SAVE MEMORY & thus save time to handle the memory by avoiding joins.
I tried to simulate your problem on `~420k` records with `4` values in smaller table.

**Approach** is to avoid join and limit problem memory space from `m x n` to at least bigger of m & n.

```
select DISTINCT t2.name
from tb10mil  t2
where (SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM #splitdata where CHARINDEX(data,t2.Problem)>0)=1
```

**RESULT:** half the time it took by approach used in question.
`(reduced from ~28 s to ~14s)`

**CON:** Approach is beneficial only if one of the table is considerably small